# How to remove spaces and print line to the next column using .format() in python?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm having a problem with printing and formatting i tried this code:

```
for line in sorted(mydictionary.line()):
    print '{0} ,'.format(key_val[0]),
    print '{0}'.format(*mydictionary[line][0]),
    print '{0}'.format(*mydictionary[line][1])
```

Output looks like this:

```
File 1
File 2
File 1
01-CA , C 900
02-AR , A 505
03-UT , U 800
04-NY , N 350
File 2
01-CA , C 500
02-AR , A 700
03-UT , U 805
04-NY , N 300
```

Is there anyway i could do formatting so it would be printed like this:

```
File 1
File 2
File 1       File 2
01-CA , C900 01-CA , C500
02-AR , A505 02-AR , A700
03-UT , U800 03-UT , U805
04-NY , N350 04-NY , N300
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post your dictionary ?

Comment: What does `mydictionary.line()` do?

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution for a greater number of lines would iterate through the lines rather than writing them all out, but something like this should do the trick:

```
l = ["" for i in range(3)]
for mydictionary in dictionaries:
    for line in sorted(mydictionary.line()):
        l[1] = l[1] + '{0} ,'.format(key_val[0])
        l[2] = l[2] + '{0} ,'.format(key_val[0])
        l[3] = l[3] + '{0} ,'.format(key_val[0])

print l[1]
print l[2]
print l[3]
```